# C++ | Avoiding repetitive config file reading within a DLL

Tags: c++, dll

I've made DLL file that handles a lot of API requests (currently ca. 20-30 per second) from different applications. For the API access, you require to be whitelisted. In the past this was done over the IPv4/v6 whitelisting which is a bad approach for systems with a dynamic/changing IP.

I decided for a token approach, the user would have to enter the token in a config file. However, The constant "simple" reading of the config file (using config4cpp) for every request is a bottleneck.

I'm kinda out of ideas how to solve this problem.
Are there more efficient approaches? Is it possible to keep the token in the memory until the next request?

Thankful for any advice :)

Comment: How secure does it have to be? You could keep an `unordered_map<ip, timestamp>` to keep track of when a client "logged in". Only request a client to supply credentials if it's not in the map or the timestamp is too old.

Comment: It doesn't have to be too secure. I only want to be able to match each request with an (responsible) user / server. I'm currently thinking about generating some simple hash based on hardware + calling application. 

Only need to find very simple, performant hashing method, and test it out.

Comment: You could do that or just  let the client authenticate itself once and keep that authentication valid for a certain amount of time using the hash based `unordered_map` I suggested. You could possibly put the mac address in there instead: `unordered_map<mac, timestamp>`